# is it possible to add -1 value in add instruction in MIPS32

Tags: spim, mars-simulator, qtspim, pcspim

is it this instruction is correct Using SPIM ?

add $t1,$zero,-1

after run program the $t1 is fill by "ffffffff"

Comment: ffffffff is the hex for -1

Comment: It's not an accepted practice on SO to post a question with code that has a bug, get an answer, and then edit the question with the answer [obscuring the original code and the reason why you asked the question in the first place]. This makes both the question and the answer make no sense. Questions and answers have value for others that might have a similar problem. It is acceptable to edit your question and append updated code to the bottom, but here, it's a one liner, so hardly worth it. I've rolled back the edit

Answer (score 1):

You want `addi` instead of `add`

```
addi $t1, $zero, -1
```

The `addi` instruction sign-extends the 16-bit immediate, so it should place `0xffffffff` in `$t1`.

Comment: Thanks , i correct my question , but please answer fully my question